# How can I send a text to a TEdit within a Form from another application (service)?

Tags: delphi, winapi, sendmessage, postmessage

I want to send a barcode to TEdit called edtCodigo inside a window called TfrmGuiaMovimiento, I am using the following code:

```
var
  h: HWND;
  codigo: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  h := FindWindow('TfrmGuiaMovimiento',nil);
  if h > 0 then
  begin
    codigo := '7665009887781';
    h := FindWindowEx(h, 0, 'edtCodigo', nil);
    if h > 0 then
    begin
      for i := 1 to codigo.Length do SendMessage(h, WM_CHAR, Ord(codigo[i]), 0);
      PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
    end;
  end;
 end;
```

But I have not got it.
But sending the Handle directly works.

Comment: You can't send messages from a service to a desktop application. They are both running in a different session *(and Window Station mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976140/how-to-pass-a-message-from-windows-service-to-windows-desktop-application-using/12979450#12979450))*. The crux of the linked answer is to use another mechanism to pass information: named pipes, sockets, ...

Comment: Or, have the service spawn a new process in the same desktop session as the `TEdit` window using `CreateProcessAsUser()`, and then that process can set the `TEdit` text using `WM_SETTEXT`

Comment: Will this ever end? [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: @IInspectable: "Will this ever end?" - not likely, because there are too many bad examples floating around that do it, and newbies find them and think they are ok to use, not knowing any better.

Answer (score -2):

```
procedure TMainForm.SendMsgToTele;
var
    h : HWND;
    hchild : HWND;
    aTemp      : array[0..200] of Char;
    sClassName : String;
    //tmpI : Integer;
Begin
    h := FindWindow(nil, 'MT5SENDER');
    if IsWindow(h) then
    Begin
        hchild := FindWindowEx(h, 0, 'TEdit', nil);
        if hchild > 0  then
        Begin
            DateTimeToString(sClassName, 'd.m.yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz', Now);
            sClassName := sClassName ;
            StrPCopy(aTemp,sClassName);
            SendMessage(hchild,WM_SETTEXT,SizeOf(aTemp),Integer(@aTemp));
            SendMessage(h, WM_USER+1, 123, 520);
        End;
    End;
End;
```